# Android NDK - ffmpeg header files not found by compiler

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am trying to use the ffmpeg libraries with Android NDK in the experimental plugin.

I am attempting to compile this example:
https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/android-ffmpeg-tutorial01/jni/tutorial01.c

My problem is that the header files are not being found by the compiler:

```
Error:(13, 32) libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
```

I added flags to build.grade:

```
cppFlags += "-ilibavcodec -ilibavutil -ilibavformat -ilibswscale"
ldFlags += "-llibavcodec -llibavutil -llibavformat -llibswscale"
```

Which seems to keep lint happy, but not the compiler. (Not sure if I have done this right?)

I Have added the header files to the /jni folder:
[image: Project folder structure]

And build.grade looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with { 
            applicationId = "roman10.tutorial.android_ffmpeg_tutorial01"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23

        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }


    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "tutorial01"
        ldLibs += ["android","log","jnigraphics","z"]
        cppFlags += "-ilibavcodec -ilibavutil -ilibavformat -ilibswscale"
        ldFlags += "-llibavcodec -llibavutil -llibavformat -llibswscale"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the plan is to use it from Java, you might want to take a look at JavaCV and JavaCPP...